# Android cursor out of bounds exception index 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve the name of a persons within my database. Currently Im getting an out of bounds error.

I know that the data exists that im trying to retrieve as I have a list view that displays all the data in the database.

IF ELSE check:

```
 NameAppointPass.open();
    String nameReturned = NameAppointPass.getName(sentID);
    if(nameReturned != "")
    {
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("returned");
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("win");
        d.setContentView(txt);
        d.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("empty");
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("Fail");
        d.setContentView(txt);
        d.show();
    }
```

Hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong.

Currently I'm getting the following error:

```
01-21 21:41:43.753: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 21:41:43.753: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybase2/com.example.flybase2.addAppointment}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

I am sending the ID of the data I want from the listview using the onclick 'long variable' as shown:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int list_posistion, long item_id)
{

    long idToPass = item_id;

    Intent setName = new Intent("com.example.flybase2.addAppointment");
    setName.putExtra("newPassedID", idToPass);
    startActivity(setName);  
}
```

This is then sent through a bundle to an object instance 'NameAppointPass' as shown:

```
NameAppointPass.open();
String nameReturned = NameAppointPass.getName(sentID);
```

The following code shows the method `getName` that query's the database and should return the name stored at the selected ID but instead I get the error:

```
public String getName(long passedID) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWAPPID, KEY_NAMEAPP,   KEY_TYPEAPP, KEY_TIMEAPP, KEY_DATEAPP, KEY_COMMENTAPP};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, columns, KEY_ROWAPPID + "=" + passedID, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cursor can be empty, you can check if the cursor has no data:

```
        if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
```

To further diagnose why the cursor is empty put log statements at various places to check if the item id is still correct.

Comment: +1, as you said `if(c != null)` does not check if the Cursor is _empty_.

Comment: @Sam I have added an 'IF ELSE' check on the returned String Sam. (as edited and shown in my original question). The programme no longer crashes if i add the check to make sure rows have been returned (i.e like Henrry has stated) but without the count check it still crashes! Also the 'IF' statement is returning true showing that 'nameReturned' is not equal to nothing i.e there is a result. Very confused at the moment! –

Comment: @user1352057 The root problem is that there are no rows where `KEY_ROWAPPID + "=" + passedID`... Double check the value of `passedID`.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this sorted. In the end i had incorrectly misnamed my variable for holding the passed ID.